# Can BIO_read fail in this context?

Tags: c, openssl

I am using `SSL_read` and `SSL_write` with `BIO`s. If I know using `BIO_ctrl_pending` how much data is in the ssl engine to read (`numToRead`), and I have enough space in the destination, can `BIO_read` return reading less bytes than `numToRead`, or even fail?

```
SSL *ssl = ...;
SSL_CTX *sslCtx = ...;
...
BIO *rBio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO *wBio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
SSL_set_bio(ssl, wBio, rBio);
...
auto numWrittenToSSL = SSL_write(ssl, data.data(), data.size());
size_t numToRead = BIO_ctrl_pending(rBio);
if(numToRead > 0){
    auto numRead = BIO_read(rBio, encryptedData.data(), numToRead); //can this fail?
}
```

Comment: man bio_read. Are the order of argument for SSL_set_bio intentional?

Comment: This is the the order used here: https://thekerneldiaries.com/2016/06/13/openssl-ssltls-within-a-different-protocol/

Comment: Bio pair seems to be different concept and he seems to have treated it differently, IIRC, BIO pair was introduced to overcome the memory BIO issues but he have used memory bio. I would suggest to use BIO pair. May be ```man SSL_set_bio```